# font with symmetrical but opposite H and N

Tags: fonts

looking for font(s) having opposite style but symmetrical H and N characters. I wish to write the name HassaN which looks the same from both side and completely symmetrical.

Comment: Maybe I'm just tired, but I don't see how that would be possible, because for H and N to be identical, they would have to be identical... And that would make them the same letter, would it not?

Comment: I can almost certainly say you won't find a font for what you need. What you should do is find a font with similar H and N and use one of those as a starting point to draw your own.

Comment: Also keep in mind that the lower case A's aren't symmetrical

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called an ambigram typeface. They're hard to find and most likely aren't free to use if you do find one. I would take a look at these generator and use them as a basis to create your own typeface for your name. http://www.dezineguide.com/inspiration/25-best-ambigram-generators-and-examples/